# Checked iterator not working

Tags: c++, templates, exception, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to run the checked iterator example from the c++ programming language (3rd edition) book, but I'm getting errors, and I think I need some help understanding, why I'm getting these errors, I'm getting the code from the book, thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>
#include <cstddef>

// using namespace std;

template<class Iter> struct iterator_traits{
    typedef typename Iter::iterator_category iterator_category;
    typedef typename Iter::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename Iter::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename Iter::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename Iter::reference reference;
};

// specialization for pointer
//template<class T> struct iterator_traits<T*>
//{
//    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
//    typedef T value_type;
//    typedef T* pointer;
//    typedef T& reference;
//    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
//};


template<class Cat, class T, class Dist=ptrdiff_t, class Ptr=T*, class Ref=T&>
struct iterator{
    typedef Cat iterator_category;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Dist difference_type;
    typedef Ptr pointer;
    typedef Ref reference;
};

template<class Ran>
typename iterator_traits<Ran>::difference_type dist_helper(Ran first, Ran last, random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    return last-first;  //rely on random access

}
template<class In >
typename iterator_traits<In>::difference_type distance(In first, In last)
{
    return dist_helper(first, last, iterator_traits<In>::iterator_category());

}


//Code
template <class Cont, class Iter=typename Cont::iterator>
class Checked_iter : public iterator_traits<Iter>{   //deriving from iterator_traits
    Iter curr;
    Cont* c;
//....

public:
    void valid(Iter p)
    {
        if ( c->end() == p)
            return;
        for(Iter pp= c->begin(); pp != c->end(); ++pp){
            if (pp==p)
                return;
        }
        throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Checked_iter& i, const Checked_iter& j)
    {
        return i.c == j.c && i.curr == j.curr;
    }
    //no default initialzer
    //use defaul t copy constructor and cop assignment.

    Checked_iter(Cont& x, Iter p):c(&x), curr(p) {valid(p);}


    //Error:Unkown type name "reference"
    reference operator*()
    {
        if (curr == c->end()) throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return *curr;
    }

    //Error:Unkown type name "pointer"
    pointer operator->()
    {
        return &*curr;                    // checked by *
    }
    //Error:Unkown type name "difference_type"
    Checked_iter operator+(difference_type d )        // for random access iterators only
    {
        if(c->end() - curr <= d )
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return Checked_iter(c ,curr+d );
    }

    //Error:Unkown type name "difference_type"
    reference operator[](difference_type d )      // for random access iterators only
    {
        if (c->end() - curr <= d)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return c[d];
    }

    Checked_iter& operator++()             // prefix ++
    {
        if (curr == c->end())
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        ++curr;
        return *this ;
    }

    Checked_iter& operator++(int)
    {
        Checked_iter tmp= *this;
        ++*this; //Checked by prefix ++
        return tmp;
    }

    Checked_iter& operator--()    //prefix--
    {
        if(curr == c->begin())
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        --curr;
        return *this;

    }

    Checked_iter& operator--(int)   //postfix
    {
        Checked_iter tmp=*this;
        --*this;       //checked by prefix --
        return tmp;

    }

   //Error:Unkown type name "difference_type"
    difference_type index() {return curr-c.begin();}  //random access only
    Iterator unchecked() {return curr;}
    //+-<
};

template<class Cont, class Iter> Checked_iter<Cont,Iter>make_checked(Cont& c, Iter i)
{
    return Checked_iter<Cont, Iter>(c,i);

}
template<class Cont>Checked_iter<Cont,typename Cont::iterator>make_checked(Cont& c)
{
    return Checked_iter<Cont, typename Cont::iterator>(c,c.begin());
}


void f_count(vector<int>& vec)
{
    int count=0;
    try{
        Checked_iter<vector<int>> p(vec, vec.begin());
        while(true){
            ++p;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    catch(out_of_range){
        cout<<"overrun after"<<count<<"tries\n";
    }
}

void test_f(){
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    vector<int> l(a, a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    print_v(l);
    f_count(l);
}

void print_v(vector<int>vec)
{
    for(aut i=vec.begin();i != vec.end(); ++i)
        cout<<*i<<" ";
}

int main()
{
    test_f();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting `unknown type name` error for `reference`, `pointer` and `difference_type`.

Comment: "*these errors*"  What errors?

Comment: //I'm getting "unknown type name" error for reference, pointer and difference_type

Comment: The first error I get with your code is `(line 39) error: ‘random_access_iterator_tag’ has not been declared`.  Please make sure your posted code reflects the question you're asking.

Comment: Ah yes, that's because I deleted the using namespace std; going to fix it now

Answer (score 4):

There already is [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) in the standard library in `<iterator>`. Your `using namespace std;` makes the one in the header visible along with your user defined one. **Remove** `using namespace std;` from the code.

The other big problem is places like here: `reference operator*()`. With templates, when you use `reference` the compiler only looks inside of `Checked_iter` to see if it exists. You need to fully qualify it like this: `typename iterator_traits<Iter>::reference operator*()` or use what is called the **injected class name**, i.e. `typename Checked_iter::reference operator*()`. Otherwise, the compiler will tell you that it does not exist. BTW, `reference`, etc. is what is known a a **dependent name**.

Once the above errors are fixed, you will need to include `<stdexcept>` to get `std::out_of_range`, etc. And prepend everything with `std::`.

Also, in `difference_type index() {return curr-c.begin();}`, `c` is a **pointer**, so you need to change to `c->begin()`.

Lots of errors... I got a [compilable program](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4xvsYI%2437):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>


template<class Iter> struct iterator_traits{
    typedef typename Iter::iterator_category iterator_category;
    typedef typename Iter::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename Iter::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename Iter::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename Iter::reference reference;
};

// specialization for pointer
//template<class T> struct iterator_traits<T*>
//{
//    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
//    typedef T value_type;
//    typedef T* pointer;
//    typedef T& reference;
//    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
//};


template<class Cat, class T, class Dist=ptrdiff_t, class Ptr=T*, class Ref=T&>
struct iterator {
    typedef Cat iterator_category;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Dist difference_type;
    typedef Ptr pointer;
    typedef Ref reference;
};

template<class Ran>
typename iterator_traits<Ran>::difference_type dist_helper(Ran first, Ran last, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    return last-first;  //rely on random access

}
template<class In >
typename iterator_traits<In>::difference_type distance(In first, In last)
{
    return dist_helper(first, last, iterator_traits<In>::iterator_category());

}


//Code
template <class Cont, class Iter=typename Cont::iterator>
class Checked_iter : public iterator_traits<Iter>{   //deriving from iterator_traits
    Iter curr;
    Cont* c;
//....
public:
    void valid(Iter p)
    {
        if ( c->end() == p)
            return;
        for(Iter pp= c->begin(); pp != c->end(); ++pp){
            if (pp==p)
                return;
        }
        throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Checked_iter& i, const Checked_iter& j)
    {
        return i.c == j.c && i.curr == j.curr;
    }
    //no default initialzer
    //use defaul t copy constructor and cop assignment.

    Checked_iter(Cont& x, Iter p):c(&x), curr(p) {valid(p);}

    typename iterator_traits<Iter>::reference operator*()
    {
        if (curr == c->end()) throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return *curr;
    }
    typename iterator_traits<Iter>::pointer operator->()
    {
        return &*curr;                    // checked by *
    }

    Checked_iter operator+(typename iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type d )        // for random access iterators only
    {
        if(c->end() - curr <= d )
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return Checked_iter(c ,curr+d );
    }

    typename iterator_traits<Iter>::reference operator[](typename iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type d )      // for random access iterators only
    {
        if (c->end() - curr <= d)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return c[d];
    }

    Checked_iter& operator++()             // prefix ++
    {
        if (curr == c->end())
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        ++curr;
        return *this ;
    }

    Checked_iter& operator++(int)
    {
        Checked_iter tmp= *this;
        ++*this; //Checked by prefix ++
        return tmp;
    }

    Checked_iter& operator--()    //prefix--
    {
        if(curr == c->begin())
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        --curr;
        return *this;

    }

    Checked_iter& operator--(int)   //postfix
    {
        Checked_iter tmp=*this;
        --*this;       //checked by prefix --
        return tmp;

    }

    typename iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type index() {return curr - c->begin();}  //random access only
    Iter unchecked() {return curr;}
    //+-<
};

template<class Cont, class Iter> Checked_iter<Cont,Iter>make_checked(Cont& c, Iter i)
{
    return Checked_iter<Cont, Iter>(c,i);

}
template<class Cont>Checked_iter<Cont,typename Cont::iterator>make_checked(Cont& c)
{
    return Checked_iter<Cont, typename Cont::iterator>(c,c.begin());
}


void f_count(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    int count=0;
    try{
        Checked_iter<std::vector<int>> p(vec, vec.begin());
        while(true){
            ++p;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range){
        std::cout<<"overrun after"<<count<<"tries\n";
    }
}

void print_v(std::vector<int>vec)
{
    for(auto i=vec.begin();i != vec.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<*i<<" ";
}

void test_f(){
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> l(a, a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    print_v(l);
    f_count(l);
}

int main()
{
    test_f();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks , this compiles, but when I try to test it with sort algorithm, I start getting error in Checked_iter `operator+(typename iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type d )
    {
        if(c->end() - curr <= d )
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return Checked_iter(c ,curr+d );
    }`

Comment: the error is in curr+d,  why is that, can you help me please?

Comment: @user1653150: I don't have time right now to look, but if you post the code, I will look at it and get back to you.

Comment: `void mysort(std::vector<int>& vec){
    
    try{
        typedef Checked_iter<std::vector<int>::iterator> PI;
        PI pfirst=make_checked(vec);
  Checked_iter<std::vector<int>> plast(vec, vec.end());
        sort(pfirst, plast);
        print_v(vec);
    }
    
    catch(out_of_bounds<std::vector<int>>excep){
        std::cout<<excep.what()<<" "<<excep.m_index<<" "<<"tries\n";
    }
}`

Comment: I added this function to sort the vector elements using checked_iter, but I'm getting the aforementioned error. thanks

Comment: @user1653150: mainly you are missing a bunch of operators. i.e. `operator!=`, etc.